# Mule message enricher from jdbc source

Tags: esb, mule

I'd like to enrich the current message with two variables, LAST_POLL_START and LAST_POLL_END. These variables are then going to be used to build another jdbc query.

However, I cannot understand how I should use the enricher. The code I've tried is below, and it is inspired by the code found [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5541?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#issue-tabs) and on [Mule's blog](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/enrich-your-experience-orchestration-and-data-enrichment-with-mule-3-1/). In my mind, this should work. I'm using mule-3.2.0, and the jdbc query works and returns the correct values.

```
<flow name="MasterFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="cronJobPoolTime" cronExpression="0 0/1 * * * ?">
        <quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
            <quartz:job-endpoint ref="jdbc_quartzDummy"/>
        </quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>      
    <flow-ref name="GetPollingTimes" />
    <!-- Do other things -->
</flow>

<!-- Below is needed when using Quartz trigger -->
<jdbc:endpoint name="jdbc_quartzDummy" connector-ref="tabuConnector" queryKey="quartzDummy" />

<flow name="GetPollingTimes">
    <enricher>
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="getPollTimes" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
        <enrich target="#[variable:last_poll_start]" source="#[map-payload:LAST_POLL_START]"/>
        <enrich target="#[variable:last_poll_end]" source="#[map-payload:LAST_POLL_END]"/>
    </enricher>
    <logger level="INFO" message="last_poll_start = #[variable:last_poll_start]" />
</flow>
```

The error message is:

```
WARN  2011-12-27 15:38:00,831 [scheduler-ESB_Worker-1] org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage: setProperty(key, value) called with null value; removing key: last_poll_start; please report the following stack trace to dev@mule.codehaus.org
java.lang.Throwable
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.setProperty(DefaultMuleMessage.java:456)
    at org.mule.expression.VariableExpressionEnricher.enrich(VariableExpressionEnricher.java:24)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.enrich(DefaultExpressionManager.java:248)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.enrich(DefaultExpressionManager.java:237)
    at org.mule.enricher.MessageEnricher.enrich(MessageEnricher.java:69)
    at org.mule.enricher.MessageEnricher.process(MessageEnricher.java:43)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:99)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:64)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:105)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:90)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:99)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:64)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:105)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:105)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:41)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:99)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:64)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:56)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:64)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:87)
    at org.mule.construct.Flow.process(Flow.java:64)
    at org.mule.config.spring.factories.FlowRefFactoryBean$1.process(FlowRefFactoryBean.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:99)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:64)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:105)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:105)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:41)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:99)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:64)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:56)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:64)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:87)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$1.process(AbstractPipeline.java:138)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:99)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:64)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:56)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:64)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:87)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:99)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:64)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:56)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:64)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:87)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:190)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:163)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:150)
    at org.mule.transport.quartz.jobs.EndpointPollingJob$1.doInTransaction(EndpointPollingJob.java:162)
    at org.mule.transport.quartz.jobs.EndpointPollingJob$1.doInTransaction(EndpointPollingJob.java:125)
    at org.mule.transaction.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:45)
    at org.mule.transport.quartz.jobs.EndpointPollingJob.doExecute(EndpointPollingJob.java:169)
    at org.mule.transport.quartz.jobs.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:36)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:534)
```

Changing the enrich source to #[payload]:

```
<enrich target="#[variable:last_poll_start]" source="#[payload]"/>
<logger level="INFO" message="last_poll_start = #[variable:last_poll_start]" />
```

Produces (from log file):

```
org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: last_poll_start = [{LAST_POLL_START=2011-12-21, LAST_POLL_END=2000-01-01}]
```

Comment: Are you sure of the casing for the keys in the map payload? map-payload:LAST_POLL_START expects a DB field name in uppercase in the map payload.

Comment: I have updated the question to show the output of using `source="#[payload]"`. That is the reason for believing that it is uppercase.

Comment: Furthermore, `source="#[payload:LAST_POLL_START]"` gives: org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: Failed to process Expression Evaluation "LAST_POLL_START"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by the previous answer, I noticed that it is possible to use the *groovy* syntax in the enricher. Here is the solution, if someone else were to run into this problem.

```
<flow name="GetPollingTimes">
    <enricher>
        <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="getPollTimes" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
        <enrich target="#[variable:last_poll_start]" source="#[groovy:payload.last_poll_start]"/>
        <enrich target="#[variable:last_poll_end]" source="#[groovy:payload.last_poll_end]"/>
    </enricher>
</flow>
```

Comment: So payload is a map with lower case keys. Does <enrich target="#[variable:last_poll_start]" source="#[map-payload:last_poll_start]"/> work then?

Comment: The following do not work: `#[payload:last_poll_start]`, `#[map-payload:last_poll_start]`, `#[map-payload:LAST_POLL_START]`, `#[payload:LAST_POLL_START]`. This, to me, is strange.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a partial solution to this problem, which uses a *groovy* script. This, however, feels like some sort of hack that I'd rather be without:

```
<flow name="GetPollingTimes">
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="getPollTimes" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
    <script:transformer>
        <script:script engine="groovy">
            <script:text>
                message.setInvocationProperty('last_poll_start', payload.last_poll_start)
                message.setInvocationProperty('last_poll_end', payload.last_poll_end)
                return payload
            </script:text>
        </script:script>
    </script:transformer>
</flow>
```